# How to disable fields within a Javascript form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What is the best way of disabling(greying out) fields within a Javascript form? I have tried the `disabled="disabled"` on both the form and its fields but neither work e.g.:

```
<form:form id="testForm" method="post" disabled="disabled" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/testSave" commandName="testForm">
    <tr>
        <td valign="top" disabled="disabled">Name:&nbsp;</td>
        <td valign="top"><form:input disabled="disabled" path="fName"/></td>
    </tr>
</form:form>
```

Any ideas on what im doing wrong here?

Comment: You can't `disable` a `<td>` element.

Comment: Hmmm...ok, so how can I 'grey-out' elements within a form?

Comment: @BradM I think the OP was just trying everything he/she could find

Comment: <input disabled>, you can't disable 'form' or 'td' elements

Comment: `<form><tr>…</tr></form>` is invalid and will not work in some browsers.

Comment: purpose of this intention?

Comment: When the form loads, I want some fields greyed out to start with - they will become enabled when the user selects from a dropdown

Comment: Ah no one pointed to OP `java != javascript`

Comment: he's using java freemarker templating engine I think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the below js sample; I hope my perception matches with your wish:

http://jsbin.com/avopuf/3/

Change css as per your requirement.

Comment: Not sure why someone down-voted this but this works - thanks for your help :)

Comment: is it possible to do this for a dropdown list in the same way?

Comment: YES, that's why in the sample the style of  "select" is added!

Comment: Why is `disabled` being added to `td`? It is not a valid attribute of the `td` tag... while it looks/works as far as concerned, I would disagree with the solution because it's not using proper HTML.

Comment: That's the concept how can you deal with this situation. However, instead of disable, we can write "controldisable". Isn't it? Nowadays, many of us use data-* attributes on html tag, that can be also used with this solution with little bit modification.

Answer (score 1):

Using JQuery you could do the following to disable all form fields for a given form:

```
$('#formId').find('input,select,textarea[,other elements]').prop('disabled', true);
```

Comment: well he said he wants it to be disabled when loaded so would make more sense to have it in the html

Comment: Given he'd included the tags JavaScript and jQuery I assumed this type of answer was welcome. It's still a solution

Comment: @Stockedout - this doesnt seem to work. I've attached this to a dropdown change listener but nothing happens: `$('#testForm').find('input,select,textarea').prop('disabled', true);` Is there another way of doing this?

Comment: It does work... check this out. http://jsfiddle.net/stokedout/uQe2H/ I can't see your full code though so can't really see what else could be wrong. You sure you've loaded JQuery?

Answer (score 1):

Well, it sort of depends on exactly what you are trying to do.

The "sure fire" way of disabling form fields is a combination of "disabled" and "readonly" on the inputs.  Between the two, you can cover everything that you could want:

- grey out the input
- make the input non-editable
- make the input non-focasable
- keep the input from being sent with the form

Since some browsers don't support the "greyed out" part of disabling, the best way to cover that is to set up a custom CSS to display disabled (or readonly) fields the way that you want them to show.

To get the right soluiton for what you want to do with your form, look here for the differences between the two attributes:  http://kreotekdev.wordpress.com/2007/11/08/disabled-vs-readonly-form-fields/

**Edit:** Additionally, you might consider replacing the disabled inputs with text, if the data is not to be sent with the form . . . less confusing to the user than having an input field that they can't use.

Comment: removing the border is an easy way to make an input field appear as text

Answer (score 0):

You can disable `input` tags, but not `td`

[td tag attributes](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_td.asp#Attributes)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you can use a reference site to brush up on HTML.  I find W3School to be a good starting point, it has tutorials and references for a variety of online technologies.

Specifically for [HTML](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/default.asp) and [HTML input tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp)

Also, how is it not working?  (Is it not greying out, or user can still type in it, ...?)

Comment: Yeh, its not greying out - although if i use the `<input type="text" disabled="disabled">` that appears to work. How does it work with labels? e.g. the 'name' part of my question?

Comment: Well.. it's not possible to "disable" a label since it is just text.  Are you saying you want it to also be displayed in grey?  If so, you need to use CSS classes on the cells containing labels. Then style it by changing the CSS class when you need to toggle between active/inactive (i.e., create two CSS styles, one for active and another for inactive labels... jQuery has an easy way to [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)).